# groovy cannot resolve with method invoke

Tags: java, groovy, lambda

Hello guys I've the next code:

```
javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl control

control.focusedProperty().addListener(

            { observableValue, t, t1 ->
                //some code
            }
    )
```

Supossed that the code is like java 8:

```
control.focusedProperty().addListener((observableValue,t,t1)->{

        //some code

    });
```

But when I try to run groovy throws the following error:

```
 ADVERTENCIA: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for    method javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty#addListener.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class com.srs.javafx.utils.textfield.ValidationTextField$_setMinLenghtValidation_closure1] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[interface javafx.beans.InvalidationListener]
[interface javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener]
```

The question is... How I can to do the next code with lamda groovy?

```
control.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `as ChangeListener` after your closure definition.